# Convert code from Lisp to F#

Tags: f#, lisp

I have the following code in Lisp:

```
(defun Is_List_Even (lista)
  (cond 
    ((null lista) t)
    ((null (cadr lista)) nil)
    (t (Is_List_Even (cddr lista)))))
```

Can someone help me to write in F#? I'm new to F# and I'm in a hurry.

Regards,
Voicu.

Comment: I took the liberty to reformat your code to Lisp standard.  A few points remain:  names are usually composed with hyphens (`is-list-even`), and you can call your list `list`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
let rec even = function
| [] -> true
| [_] -> false
| _::_::l -> even l
```